# How to learn intrinsic torsion

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geometric-structures

I want to learn about G-structure and *intrinsic torsion*. But I can find no textbook that details it.
If you can give me a reference about it, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using torsion in the sense of "torsion of a connection" or perhaps in some other sense?

Comment: The intrinsic torsion is not torsion of connection. Please read the answer by Robert Bryant.

Comment: It would help to give a reference to where you've heard about the idea, and which context  you see it used in.

Answer (score 13):

General $G$-structures are not usually treated in textbooks, other than the basic definitions, so it's not surprising that there would be few if any textbooks that treat the intrinsic torsion of $G$-structures.  However, it's a straightforward concept based on a simple question:  For a given $G$-structure, what is the obstruction to $G$ being flat to first order at every point?

For example, Riemannian metrics in dimension $n$ are $\mathrm{O}(n)$-structures on $n$-manifolds, so $G=\mathrm{O}(n)$.  It's a famous result that every Riemannian metric is flat to first order at every point (this is essentially the Fundamental Lemma of Riemannian Geometry), so the intrinsic torsion of every $G$-structure vanishes in this case.

For $G=\mathrm{U}(n)\subset\mathrm{SO}(n)$, a $G$-structure on $M^{2n}$ is what is known as an *almost Hermitian* structure on $M^{2n}$, i.e., a choice of an almost complex structure $J$ and a compatible metric $g$, which defines a canonical $2$-form $\omega$ such that $\omega(v,w) = g(Jv,w)$.  In this case, the intrinsic torsion of the $G$-structure turns out to be composed of two tensors:  the $3$-form $\mathrm{d}\omega$ and the Nijnhuis tensor $N_J$ of the almost complex structure $J$.  If they both vanish, the $G$-structure is said to be Kähler.

Of course, there is a systematic approach that defines the intrinsic torsion of $G$-structures on $n$-manifolds for any Lie subgroup $G\subset\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$. It is implicit in the works of Élie Cartan (who introduced the notion of what we now call $G$-structures).  It is made explicit in the later works of Chern, Ehresmann, Spencer and many others.  The basic point is that, given a $G$-structure $B$ on $M^n$, there is a naturally defined subbundle ${\frak{g}}_B\subset TM\otimes T^*M$, which induces a natural skew-symmetrizing mapping
$$
\delta: {\frak{g}}_B\otimes T^*M\to TM\otimes\Lambda^2(T^*M).
$$
The cokernel of $\delta$, denoted $H^{0,1}_B(M)$, is a vector bundle over $M$ that is associated to the principal $G$-bundle $B$.  The intrinsic torsion $\tau_B$ of $B$ is a section of this bundle, and $\tau_B$ vanishes at a point $x\in M$ if and only if $B$ is flat to first order at $x$.

One can find explicit formulae in the works cited above, including computations of the cokernel of $\delta$ for various $G$ of interest.  The recipe for $\tau_B$ is the following:  Given a $G$-structure $B$, let $\nabla_0$ be any connection on $M$ that is compatible with $B$.  Then $T(\nabla_0)$, the torsion of $\nabla_0$, is a section of $TM\otimes \Lambda^2(T^*M)$.  If $\nabla_1$ is any other connection on $M$ that is compatible with $B$, the difference $\nabla_1-\nabla_0$ is a section of ${\frak{g}}_B\otimes T^*M$. So $T(\nabla_1)-T(\nabla_0)$ is a section of $\delta\bigl({\frak{g}}_B\otimes T^*M\bigr)$.  Hence $\tau_B = \bigl[T(\nabla_0)\bigr]$, as a section of $H^{0,1}_B(M)$, does not depend on the choice of $\nabla_0$.  This is the *intrinsic torsion* of $B$.  Almost by definition, it's the part of the torsion of a $B$-compatible connection that is independent of the choice of such a connection.

It's important to note that, because $H^{0,1}_B(M)$ is defined as a quotient of a tensor bundle, when $G$ is not reductive it may not be possible to interpret $H^{0,1}_B(M)$ as a subbundle of some tensor bundle of $M$ (i.e., some natural subbundle of the tensor product of some number of copies of $TM$ with some other number of copies of $T^*M$).  Thus, one cannot always interpret the intrinsic torsion as some collection of tensors on $M$ in the classical sense.  This probably contributes to some confusion in the literature when people call the intrinsic torsion a 'tensor' even though it's not always interpretable as a tensor in the classical sense.

Comment: ＠Robert Bryant Thank you very much. I understood your answer. How did you learn about this？

Comment: @mfdmfd:  I first learned about it from my PhD advisor, but then read the relevant works of Cartan and Chern on the equivalence problem of Cartan.  The formulation in terms of bundle language is made explicit in papers of D. C. Spencer, but I think that the idea was 'in the air' at the time.

Comment: ＠Robert Bryant Oh, I see. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

A standard published reference (so you can cite it) which contains the definitions that Robert wrote out in his answer:

Joyce, Dominic D.(4-OX)
**[Riemannian holonomy groups and calibrated geometry.](https://mathscinet-ams-org.ucc.idm.oclc.org/mathscinet/article?mr=2292510)**
*Oxf. Grad. Texts Math., 12*
Oxford University Press, Oxford, 2007. x+303 pp.
ISBN:978-0-19-921559-1, pp. 36-39, section 2.6.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much.